# When MFC (Feature Pack) calling for CDockablePane::Serialize()?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

Does `CDockablePane::Serialize()` method is calling from MFC Feature Pack core?

I have dockable window class that inherited from `CDockablePane` class. My class override virtual `Serialize()` method and declared as serial `DECLARE_SERIAL/IMPLEMENT_SERIAL`. But MFC does not call my `Serialize()` method! Why ?
MSDN [say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984433.aspx) that `CDockablePane` class have serialization methods: `SaveState()`, `LoadState()` and `Serialize()`. First two (`SaveState()`, `LoadState()`) are *used internally* and `Serialize()` used for "*serializes the pane*". But it is not calling!

Comment: No it is not called by framework. You have to call it manually usually from `CDocument::Serialize`. `LoadState`/`SaveState` are used to save/restore pane position and state. They do use **Registry** as storage.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin thank you. :( It's very sad, I do not understand the meaning declare `CDockablePane` class as serializable.

Comment: `DECLARE_SERIAL` and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` are used to support `operator>>` and other `CArchive`-specific stuff plus runtime class info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer proposition. My class `CSerializableDockablePane` performs call for `Serialize` method when this docked pane is created or stored by framework (framework calls methods `LoadState()` and `SaveState()`).

You can use `CSerializableDockablePane` as base class for your dockable pane and overwrite virtual `Serialize()` method for your need.

**Code:**

```
class CSerializableDockablePane
    : public CDockablePane
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CSerializableDockablePane)

public:
    typedef CDockablePane TBase;

public:
    CSerializableDockablePane();
    virtual ~CSerializableDockablePane();

    virtual BOOL            LoadState(LPCTSTR lpszProfileName = NULL, int nIndex = -1, UINT uiID = (UINT)-1);
    virtual BOOL            SaveState(LPCTSTR lpszProfileName = NULL, int nIndex = -1, UINT uiID = (UINT)-1);
    virtual void            Serialize(CArchive& ar);
};



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CSerializableDockablePane

#define _MFC_DOCVIEW_PROFILE _T("DockableViews")
#define _REG_UI_DOCVIEWSECTION_FMT _T("%TsSerializableDockablePane-%d")
#define _REG_UI_DOCVIEWSECTION_FMT_EX _T("%TsSerializableDockablePane-%d%x")
#define _REG_UI_SETTINGS _T("Settings")

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CSerializableDockablePane, CSerializableDockablePane::TBase, VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA | 2)

CSerializableDockablePane::CSerializableDockablePane()
{
}

CSerializableDockablePane::~CSerializableDockablePane()
{
}

BOOL CSerializableDockablePane::LoadState(LPCTSTR lpszProfileName /*= NULL*/, int nIndex /*= -1*/, UINT uiID /*= (UINT)-1*/)
{
    BOOL bRes = TBase::LoadState(lpszProfileName, nIndex, uiID);
    if (bRes) {

        const CString strProfileName = ::AFXGetRegPath(_MFC_DOCVIEW_PROFILE, lpszProfileName);
        if (nIndex == -1) {
            nIndex = GetDlgCtrlID();
        }

        CString strSection;
        if (uiID == (UINT)-1) {
            strSection.Format(_REG_UI_DOCVIEWSECTION_FMT, (LPCTSTR)strProfileName, nIndex);
        }
        else {
            strSection.Format(_REG_UI_DOCVIEWSECTION_FMT_EX, (LPCTSTR)strProfileName, nIndex, uiID);
        }

        LPBYTE lpbData = nullptr;
        UINT uiDataSize = 0;

        CSettingsStoreSP regSP;
        CSettingsStore& reg = regSP.Create(FALSE, TRUE);

        if (!reg.Open(strSection)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (!reg.Read(_REG_UI_SETTINGS, &lpbData, &uiDataSize)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        try
        {
            CMemFile file(lpbData, uiDataSize);
            CArchive ar(&file, CArchive::load);

            Serialize(ar);
            bRes = TRUE;
        }
        catch (CMemoryException* pEx)
        {
            pEx->Delete();
            TRACE(_T("Memory exception in CSerializableDockablePane::LoadState()!\n"));
        }
        catch (CArchiveException* pEx)
        {
            pEx->Delete();
            TRACE(_T("CArchiveException exception in CSerializableDockablePane::LoadState()!\n"));
        }

        if (lpbData != nullptr) {
            delete[] lpbData;
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}

BOOL CSerializableDockablePane::SaveState(LPCTSTR lpszProfileName /*= NULL*/, int nIndex /*= -1*/, UINT uiID /*= (UINT)-1*/)
{
    BOOL bRes = TBase::SaveState(lpszProfileName, nIndex, uiID);
    if (bRes) {

        const CString strProfileName = ::AFXGetRegPath(_MFC_DOCVIEW_PROFILE, lpszProfileName);
        if (nIndex == -1) {
            nIndex = GetDlgCtrlID();
        }

        CString strSection;
        if (uiID == (UINT)-1) {
            strSection.Format(_REG_UI_DOCVIEWSECTION_FMT, (LPCTSTR)strProfileName, nIndex);
        }
        else {
            strSection.Format(_REG_UI_DOCVIEWSECTION_FMT_EX, (LPCTSTR)strProfileName, nIndex, uiID);
        }

        try
        {
            CMemFile file;

            {
                CArchive ar(&file, CArchive::store);

                Serialize(ar);
                ar.Flush();
            }

            UINT uiDataSize = (UINT)file.GetLength();
            LPBYTE lpbData = file.Detach();

            if (lpbData != NULL)
            {
                CSettingsStoreSP regSP;
                CSettingsStore& reg = regSP.Create(FALSE, FALSE);

                if (reg.CreateKey(strSection)) {
                    bRes = reg.Write(_REG_UI_SETTINGS, lpbData, uiDataSize);
                }

                free(lpbData);
            }
        }
        catch (CMemoryException* pEx)
        {
            pEx->Delete();
            TRACE(_T("Memory exception in CSerializableDockablePane::SaveState()!\n"));
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}

void CSerializableDockablePane::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    TBase::Serialize(ar);
}
// CSerializableDockablePane
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the `Serialize()` method is not called by MFC framework automatically. You have to call it manually usually from `CDocument::Serialize()`. `LoadState()` and `SaveState()` methods are used to save/restore pane position and state. They do use **Registry** as storage.

As for `DECLARE_SERIAL` and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` they are used to support `operator>>` and other `CArchive`-specific things plus runtime class information. So you'll be able to use `BOOL IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(...))` automagically.

Comment: No, `IsKinfOf` works by MFC class information ( see `DECLARE_DYNAMIC()` macro ). `DECLARE_SERIAL` implements `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` but main its code for serialization support!